# Load CKAN dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, ckan

I have a few doubt about ckan:

**How to:**

1. load a CKAN dataset from web
2. transform this dataset into a pandas dataframe

**And** i need have a register in ckan website to query the data?

I am using Pyhton 3.6.1

**Edit 2:**
I had tried the follow code:

```
 import urllib
url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4&q=CNPJ_FUNDO:11.286.399/0001-35'
fileobj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(fileobj.read())
```

But, the result are like this:

> b'{"help":
>   "http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
>   "success": true, "result": {"resource_id":
>   "92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4", "fields": [{"type": "int4",
>   "id": "_id"}, {"type": "text", "id": "CNPJ_FUNDO"}, {"type":
>   "timestamp", "id": "DT_COMPTC"}, {"type": "numeric", "id":
>   "VL_TOTAL"}, {"type": "numeric", "id": "VL_QUOTA"}, {"type":
>   "numeric", "id": "VL_PATRIM_LIQ"}, {"type": "numeric", "id":
>   "CAPTC_DIA"}, {"type": "numeric", "id": "RESG_DIA"}, {"type":
>   "numeric", "id": "NR_COTST"}, {"type": "int8", "id": "_full_count"},
>   {"type": "float4", "id": "rank"}], "q":
>   "CNPJ_FUNDO:11.286.399/0001-35", "records": [], "_links": {"start":
>   "/api/action/datastore_search?q=CNPJ_FUNDO%3A11.286.399%2F0001-35&resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4", "next":
>   "/api/action/datastore_search?q=CNPJ_FUNDO%3A11.286.399%2F0001-35&offset=100&resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4"}}}'

I need a result like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9aFJ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As currently stated your question is a bit too generic. You are likely to get better answers if you update your question in order to show you have tried so far and share your previous research on the subject.

Comment: BTW there is a Python example in the very page you linked (click on the "API de Dados" link and scroll down), are you having any problem with that?

Comment: i don't tried anything because is this the doubt: how to research/load the ckan dataset using a web link.

Comment: the website example don't show the needed result. The needed result is a table like this: http://dados.cvm.gov.br/dataset/fi-doc-inf_diario/resource/92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4?view_id=f1e82110-9d99-4e9b-9789-6fee7c3efa03

Comment: The site is telling you how to load the dataset if you click the "API de Dados" link, what is your doubt? It even gives a Python example. Please try it first, if you find any problem update your question.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. load a CKAN dataset from web

The website you linked has a Python example in the link "API de Dados":

```
import urllib
url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4&limit=5&q=title:jones'
fileobj = urllib.urlopen(url)
print fileobj.read()
```

> 2. transform this dataset into a pandas dataframe

Do as you do with any JSON dataset, parse it and load in a data frame (there is nothing specific to ckan here):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> response = json.loads(fileobj.read())
>>> pd.DataFrame(response['result']['records'])

  CAPTC_DIA          CNPJ_FUNDO            DT_COMPTC NR_COTST RESG_DIA  \
0      0.00  00.017.024/0001-53  2017-07-03T00:00:00        1     0.00   
1      0.00  00.017.024/0001-53  2017-07-04T00:00:00        1     0.00   
2      0.00  00.017.024/0001-53  2017-07-05T00:00:00        1     0.00   
3      0.00  00.017.024/0001-53  2017-07-06T00:00:00        1     0.00   
4      0.00  00.017.024/0001-53  2017-07-07T00:00:00        1     0.00   

  VL_PATRIM_LIQ         VL_QUOTA    VL_TOTAL  _id  
0    1111752.99  25.249352000000  1111831.24    1  
1    1112087.29  25.256944400000  1112268.26    2  
2    1112415.28  25.264393500000  1112716.06    3  
3    1112754.06  25.272087600000  1113165.75    4  
4    1113096.62  25.279867600000  1113293.06    5
```

> And i need have a register in ckan website to query the data?

You don't need to register at the website you link, I was able to retrieve the data without registering. I prefer to use the `requests` library:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = params={
    'resource_id': '92741280-58fc-446b-b436-931faaca4fb4', 
    'limit': 5,
}
url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/api/action/datastore_search'
r = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r['result']['records'])
```

Looks like the [`limit` and `offset` parameters probably behave like in SQL](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=sql+limit+and+offset&oq=sql+limit+and+offset). You may have to convert columns to numeric/date types, again this is nothing specific to ckan and you can find answers on how to do that in the pandas documentation.

```
>>> df.describe()
            _id
count  5.000000
mean   3.000000
std    1.581139
min    1.000000
25%    2.000000
50%    3.000000
75%    4.000000
max    5.000000
```

Converting is easy enough:

```
>>> for col in ('CAPTC_DIA', 'NR_COTST', 'RESG_DIA', 'VL_PATRIM_LIQ', 'VL_QUOTA', 'VL_TOTAL'):
...    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])

>>> df['DT_COMPTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT_COMPTC'])

>>> df.describe()
       CAPTC_DIA  NR_COTST  RESG_DIA  VL_PATRIM_LIQ   VL_QUOTA      VL_TOTAL  \
count        5.0       5.0       5.0   5.000000e+00   5.000000  5.000000e+00
mean         0.0       1.0       0.0   1.112421e+06  25.264529  1.112655e+06
std          0.0       0.0       0.0   5.303356e+02   0.012045  6.123444e+02
min          0.0       1.0       0.0   1.111753e+06  25.249352  1.111831e+06
25%          0.0       1.0       0.0   1.112087e+06  25.256944  1.112268e+06
50%          0.0       1.0       0.0   1.112415e+06  25.264394  1.112716e+06
75%          0.0       1.0       0.0   1.112754e+06  25.272088  1.113166e+06
max          0.0       1.0       0.0   1.113097e+06  25.279868  1.113293e+06

            _id  
count  5.000000  
mean   3.000000  
std    1.581139  
min    1.000000  
25%    2.000000  
50%    3.000000  
75%    4.000000  
max    5.000000
```